# react-query: reactive useMutation results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-query

I'm trying to switch from zustand to react-query as my central cache. I can get reactive query results with `useQuery(queryKey, queryFn)`. However, I want to get reactive results for mutations as well. So I tried the following:

```
useMutation(mutationFn, {
 onSuccess: (d, i) => queryClient.setQueryData(queryKey, d),
});
```

The problem is how to get the reactive result.

I considered `useQuery(queryKey)` but the [API](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useQuery) mentions `queryFn` is required unless defaults are setup. In my current use case, I don't plan on updating that `queryKey` unless its via a mutation so I don't have a `queryFn`. I can't use `queryClient.getQueryData(queryKey)` since it's not reactive.

How can I get the mutation's reactive result?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `useQuery` without a `queryFn` as it will error out.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-reactive-mutation-results-txcz9?file=/src/index.js

A feature request is in progress to handle the mutations side.

https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/issues/2304

Comment: your example returns you the data from the cache, which it has because you put it there manually. It then does a background refetch, which fails, you can see this in the console where it says: `Missing queryFn`. So the docs are correct on this, and I don't know what you are trying to achieve by having a query without a queryFn

Comment: @TkDodo I was trying to cache and reactively access my mutations result. Didn't know how else without using a separate state management.